# 2004 Accord V6 auto transmission fluid

Tags: honda, automatic-transmission, accord

I just changed the transmission in 2004 Honda accord v6. How much transmission fluid do I need?

The torque converter and all has been drained on the new one.

Comment: Be careful, you might have had to pre-fill some components as you installed them or else filling it might not be enough.

Answer (score 4):

I got this information from page 274 of this online [Honda Accord user manual](https://cdn.dealereprocess.org/cdn/servicemanuals/honda/2004-accord.pdf) -

[image]

[image]

So for a completely empty transmission and torque converter, you need 7.2 litres.